# Python 2.7 - GraphLab : ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Tags: python, graphlab

I'm trying to create a K-means model using normalised tf-idf as the feature. I'm getting 'ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero'. Below is the code. Please let me know if more details are required.

```
    import graphlab as gl

            data = gl.SFrame(data)
            data['tf_idf'] = gl.text_analytics.tf_idf(data['text'])

            def normalize(d, target=1.0):
                raw = sum(d.values())
                try:
                    factor = target/raw
                except ZeroDivisionError:
                    print 'Zero Error in file ', d['file_name']
                return {key:value*factor for key,value in d.iteritems()}

            data['tf_idf_norm'] = data['tf_idf'].apply(normalize)

            print data[0]

            {'file_name': 'ap-4081.pdf.txt', 
             'tf_idf_norm': {'september': 0.006612160101629999, 'issued': 0.004914445160361691, 'declaration': 0.018380116959675345, 'pursuant': 0.0015236875459684344, 'held': 0.006661456734504585, 'edt': 0.01993691915396277, 'its': 0.0018031759056466382, 'before': 0.000628458524686868, 'prehearing': 0.03603879166997583, 'mail': 0.010151784816687623, 'administrative': 0.0038202023891634983, 'scheduled': 0.02675584978978817, 'division': 0.003714090891806661, 'greater': 0.014401469513143977, 'express': 0.015442536961835316, 'judge': 0.0056255693137487245, 'postal': 0.01448758917369378, 'timely': 0.009547408004733245, 'postponing': 0.023771054663189694, 'james': 0.013851907261754153, 'establishing': 0.015525275482306627, 'securities': 0.0009534453943686734, 'release': 0.000994876598539298, 'served': 0.007549203784675396, 'cliffs': 0.040192712832365154, 'realty': 0.027963087504615878, 'financial': 0.006067940095145491, 'instituting': 0.0047412698163078965, 'are': 0.0024740930507990123, 'fails': 0.013316168540074749, 'proceeding': 0.0031604332608950046, 'appear': 0.010272410560940281, 'for': 0.00039400705802880267, 'defend': 0.01741380246078061, 'asia': 0.028632052997003922, 'deemed': 0.008702433747892771, 'august': 0.04977168128599991, 'exchange': 0.0005249518349832802, 'answers': 0.015575372135328506, 'respondents': 0.022052537701443286, 'corp': 0.010689517733349321, 'eastland': 0.04688688851929564, 'revoked': 0.013668927632973267, 'against': 0.00388458245265655, 'telephonic': 0.016974699222910256, 'incorporated': 0.014218288205022512, 'ltd': 0.014589362228277223, 'postponed': 0.0209823757486391, 'otherwise': 0.007582793422109354, 'respondent': 0.0054516655648239295, 'washington': 0.005091825331541719, 'hearing': 0.02249732139496055, 'registration': 0.00852794089032502, 'conference': 0.03047929459424198, 'america': 0.001440915940409403, 'service': 0.01231944374204312, 'holdings': 0.013681846704902636, 'due': 0.006408671617186687, 'commission': 0.0003703379846648254, 'enforcement': 0.0040660794190181156, 'that': 0.0008014938443938574, 'filed': 0.004601893518537033, 'with': 0.0011834598692978579, 'commence': 0.01644634375933502, 'accordance': 0.006995433441162778, 'default': 0.010296776564423474, 'rulings': 0.00878134432538458, 'will': 0.004454693796954499, 'matter': 0.0008886177351788676, 'were': 0.00495349246481796, 'grimes': 0.019846163536283806, 'and': 0.00019120815327678883, 'states': 0.0006306247910547858, 'file': 0.0014093253240757065, 'scheduling': 0.015608961772762466, 'any': 0.0024796720760966906, 'united': 0.0007573801483105002, 'answer': 0.010898516012467644, 'granite': 0.03675899168009445, 'practice': 0.005139863202847838, 'shall': 0.004531342051741035, 'act': 0.0012356449848511732, 'law': 0.003763823781424106, 'oip': 0.051638100949650705, 'rule': 0.0022896158932922445, 'order': 0.0013019082720686934, 'proceedings': 0.005189982291505062, 'the': 0.0003944745275206197, 'section': 0.0023716422033868588}, 
             'tf_idf': {'september': 0.9050645370154226, 'issued': 0.6726833539094077, 'declaration': 2.515848344672878, 'pursuant': 0.20856052215192625, 'held': 0.9118122009441979, 'edt': 2.7289415601335865, 'its': 0.24681655330746285, 'before': 0.08602264841392737, 'prehearing': 4.93294654032065, 'mail': 1.3895641188014474, 'administrative': 0.5229047169927326, 'scheduled': 3.662308599647982, 'division': 0.5083803026181314, 'greater': 1.97125585843607, 'express': 2.113755921043353, 'judge': 0.7700211743422583, 'postal': 1.9830438141881122, 'timely': 1.306837746316985, 'postponing': 3.253753425874317, 'james': 1.8960324371984822, 'establishing': 2.125081070400406, 'securities': 0.1305064609991892, 'release': 0.1361775144891726, 'served': 1.0333259514584336, 'cliffs': 5.501530282373367, 'financial': 0.8305723558472731, 'registration': 1.1672943115358345, 'are': 0.3386508867204352, 'fails': 1.8227011641129327, 'proceeding': 0.43259631074797295, 'appear': 1.4060752258672398, 'for': 0.053931213109576576, 'section': 0.3246275377157642, 'asia': 3.9191210423271863, 'deemed': 1.191178684406377, 'august': 6.812687985048638, 'exchange': 0.07185477698391116, 'answers': 2.1319382401265434, 'respondents': 3.018524887177448, 'corp': 1.4631683549022034, 'eastland': 6.417821014247522, 'revoked': 1.8709864052723948, 'against': 0.531716982797367, 'telephonic': 2.323476452025422, 'incorporated': 1.9461822208839539, 'ltd': 1.9969743877240589, 'postponed': 2.87204240377426, 'otherwise': 1.037923660707063, 'respondent': 0.7462174379555567, 'washington': 0.696962938801067, 'hearing': 3.07940634519689, 'instituting': 0.648979320707021, 'conference': 4.171969254600169, 'law': 0.5151876808461564, 'service': 1.686270670295957, 'holdings': 1.8727547523291366, 'due': 0.8772112775465153, 'commission': 0.050691418761513035, 'enforcement': 0.5565600696713887, 'that': 0.10970751525181831, 'realty': 3.827553848801696, 'with': 0.16199056620216346, 'commence': 2.2511557904457957, 'accordance': 0.9575265316227637, 'default': 1.4094104151733782, 'rulings': 1.2019798695237245, 'will': 0.6097531392036623, 'matter': 0.12163292883290797, 'were': 0.6780281020682886, 'grimes': 2.7165190401350294, 'and': 0.026172342480994967, 'states': 0.08631916435383152, 'file': 0.19290675850759448, 'scheduling': 2.136535949375173, 'any': 0.33941453700573243, 'united': 0.10366928548906945, 'proceedings': 0.7103985456464252, 'answer': 1.4917757884518863, 'granite': 5.031526653127632, 'practice': 0.7035383049574554, 'shall': 0.6202446603049608, 'act': 0.1691336021724683, 'america': 0.19723084414778347, 'oip': 7.068161268029516, 'rule': 0.31339987486008647, 'order': 0.17820364137975558, 'filed': 0.629901660385122, 'the': 0.05399519977243369, 'defend': 2.3835803760951273}, 
             'text': 'united states america before the securities and exchange commission washington administrative proceedings rulings release august administrative proceeding file the matter eastland financial corp granite cliffs incorporated and greater asia realty holdings ltd order postponing hearing and scheduling prehearing conference august the securities and exchange commission issued order instituting proceedings oip against respondents pursuant section the securities exchange act the hearing scheduled commence august august the division enforcement filed declaration service establishing that respondents were served with the oip postal service express mail august accordance with rule practice respondents answers are due august oip order that the hearing scheduled for august postponed and telephonic prehearing conference shall held edt september any respondent that fails timely file answer appear the prehearing conference otherwise defend the proceeding will deemed default and the registration its securities will revoked oip james grimes administrative law judge'}


             model = gl.clustering.kmeans.create(data,num_clusters=4,features=['tf_idf_norm'])  

[ERROR] graphlab.toolkits._main: Toolkit error: Exception in python callback function evaluation: 
    ZeroDivisionError('float division by zero',): 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "graphlab/cython/cy_pylambda_workers.pyx", line 426, in graphlab.cython.cy_pylambda_workers._eval_lambda
      File "graphlab/cython/cy_pylambda_workers.pyx", line 169, in graphlab.cython.cy_pylambda_workers.lambda_evaluator.eval_simple
      File "<ipython-input-14-405770e0af16>", line 3, in normalize
    ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

    ERROR:graphlab.toolkits._main:Toolkit error: Exception in python callback function evaluation: 
    ZeroDivisionError('float division by zero',): 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "graphlab/cython/cy_pylambda_workers.pyx", line 426, in graphlab.cython.cy_pylambda_workers._eval_lambda
      File "graphlab/cython/cy_pylambda_workers.pyx", line 169, in graphlab.cython.cy_pylambda_workers.lambda_evaluator.eval_simple
      File "<ipython-input-14-405770e0af16>", line 3, in normalize
    ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ToolkitError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-17-1591a6c5df9a> in <module>()
    ----> 1 model = gl.clustering.kmeans.create(data,num_clusters=4,features=['tf_idf_norm'])

    /home/praveen/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/toolkits/clustering/kmeans.pyc in create(dataset, num_clusters, features, label, initial_centers, max_iterations, batch_size, verbose)
        659 
        660     ## Create and return the model
    --> 661     params = _gl.toolkits._main.run('kmeans_train', opts, verbose)
        662     return KmeansModel(params['model'])

    /home/praveen/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/toolkits/_main.pyc in run(toolkit_name, options, verbose, show_progress)
         87         _get_metric_tracker().track(metric_name, value=1, properties=track_props, send_sys_info=False)
         88 
    ---> 89         raise ToolkitError(str(message))

    ToolkitError: Exception in python callback function evaluation: 
    ZeroDivisionError('float division by zero',): 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "graphlab/cython/cy_pylambda_workers.pyx", line 426, in graphlab.cython.cy_pylambda_workers._eval_lambda
      File "graphlab/cython/cy_pylambda_workers.pyx", line 169, in graphlab.cython.cy_pylambda_workers.lambda_evaluator.eval_simple
      File "<ipython-input-14-405770e0af16>", line 3, in normalize
    ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

**UPDATE:**

The below line works fine.

```
data['tf_idf_norm'] = data['tf_idf'].apply(lambda x: {key:value*(1.0/sum(x.values())) for key, value in x.iteritems()})
```

Answer (score 2):

iPython I've seen deliver some weird errors that are sometimes unrelated. I looked at this first as an actual division by zero error (which is, a real possibility with this code you should probably account for with an except ZeroDivisionError handler) but your iPython trace said the problem started here: print data['tf_idf_norm'][0]

Which is unrelated to where your zero division error could take place. So despite what the trace seems to imply, I'm tempted to say your biggest problem is that you are trying to reference the values in data['td_idf_norm'] by an index which you can't do with a dictionary. When I create a dictionary similar to yours and try to reference it in the Python shell as you do it gives "KeyError"

If you want to view individual values in a dictionary you need to reference them by key data['td_idf_norm']['(key you want to view/print)'] or you need to iterate through them. Dictionaries are unordered and thus don't have an index like you are trying to use with [0]

**UPDATE**

Here is the code I used to test out the main logic:

```
def normalize(d, target=1.0):
    raw = sum(d.values())
    try:
        factor = target/raw
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print d
        print "Tried to divide by zero"
        raise
    return {key:value*factor for key, value in d.iteritems()}


input['tf_idf_norm'] = normalize(input['tf_idf'])

print input['tf_idf_norm']
```

With this handling, if a zero ever makes it in here somehow, it should raise it for you with the offending line of data that caused it. If you find an offending line of data and it still looks like the error is invalid post that line of data as an update.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Wasn't aware that a row in a sFrame is actually a dictionary.

Comment: But I still get the same error when I use the normalised column as the feature to train a K-means model. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I don't have your raw data so its hard to recreate, but I'll try to mock something up tonight when I'm home. Is the tf_idf in your dictionary example above a good representation of what all the inputs will look like? Do you know specifically which input is causing the break or is it any input?

Comment: I tried the exception handle but the code ran well, no exceptions were thrown. If it helps, I have the data in github https://github.com/drah-kah-ris/tensorflow_tryouts/blob/master/Text_full.zip