# Getting ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphlab

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to divide a whole number column by the number of keys in my dictionary. I have added + 1 to the denominator to avoid division by 0 but still I'm getting the ZeroDivisionError.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Code:

```
Questions_not_Duplicate_v2['bigram_match_frac'] = Questions_not_Duplicate_v2.apply(lambda x: (x['bigram_match']*1.0)/(len(set(x['bi_gram_1'].keys()))+1))
Questions_not_Duplicate_v2['bigram_match_frac'].show()
```

Error :

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-4e14321362d6> in <module>()
----> 1 Questions_not_Duplicate_v2['bigram_match_frac'].show()

C:\Users\rakesh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\graphlab\data_structures\sarray.pyc in show(self, view)
2853         """
2854         from ..visualization.show import show
-> 2855         show(self, view=view)
2856 
2857     def item_length(self):

C:\Users\rakesh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\multipledispatch\dispatcher.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
162             self._cache[types] = func
163         try:
--> 164             return func(*args, **kwargs)
165 
166         except MDNotImplementedError:

C:\Users\rakesh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\graphlab\canvas\glc_display_dispatch.pyc in show(obj, **kwargs)
 19 
 20     graphlab.canvas.inspect.find_vars(obj)
---> 21     return graphlab.canvas.show(graphlab.canvas.views.sarray.SArrayView(obj, params=kwargs))
 22 
 23 

C:\Users\rakesh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\graphlab\canvas\utils.pyc in show(variable)
129         get_target().state.set_selected_variable(variable)
130         variable.validate_js_component_name(variable.get_js_component())
--> 131     return get_target().show()
132 
133 def _get_id(ref):

C:\Users\rakesh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\graphlab\canvas\target.pyc in show(self, variable)
169             'ipython': True,
170         }
--> 171         data.update(view.get_staticdata())
172 
173         import IPython

C:\Users\rakesh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\graphlab\canvas\views\sarray.pyc in get_staticdata(self)
 67             }
 68         return {
---> 69             'sketch': self.get_sketch(background=False),
 70             'histogram': self.__get_histogram_static()
 71         }

C:\Users\rakesh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\graphlab\canvas\views\sarray.pyc in get_sketch(self, background, cached_only)
297             else:
298                 if self.__cached_sketch is None:
--> 299                     self.__cached_sketch = sa.sketch_summary(background=background)
300                 sk = self.__cached_sketch
301                 if issubclass(sa.dtype(), dict):

C:\Users\rakesh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\graphlab\data_structures\sarray.pyc in sketch_summary(self, background, sub_sketch_keys)
2742             sub_sketch_keys = list()
2743 
-> 2744         return Sketch(self, background, sub_sketch_keys = sub_sketch_keys)
2745 
2746     def append(self, other):

C:\Users\rakesh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\graphlab\data_structures\sketch.pyc in __init__(self, array, background, sub_sketch_keys, _proxy)
170                 raise TypeError("Sketch object can only be constructed from SArrays")
171 
--> 172             self.__proxy__.construct_from_sarray(array.__proxy__, background, sub_sketch_keys)
173 
174     def __repr__(self):

graphlab\cython\cy_sketch.pyx in 
graphlab.cython.cy_sketch.UnitySketchProxy.construct_from_sarray()

graphlab\cython\cy_sketch.pyx in 
graphlab.cython.cy_sketch.UnitySketchProxy.construct_from_sarray()

RuntimeError: Runtime Exception. Exception in python callback function evaluation: 
ZeroDivisionError('float division by zero',): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "graphlab\cython\cy_pylambda_workers.pyx", line 450, in graphlab.cython.cy_pylambda_workers._eval_lambda_by_sframe_rows
File "graphlab\cython\cy_pylambda_workers.pyx", line 221, in graphlab.cython.cy_pylambda_workers.lambda_evaluator.eval_sframe_rows
File "<ipython-input-61-c7d77added1c>", line 3, in <lambda>
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

The error seems very similar to : [Python 2.7 - GraphLab : ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868487/python-2-7-graphlab-zerodivisionerror-float-division-by-zero), but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: According to math, division goes before the plus.

Comment: @domenukk I have used brackets just to negate that